# convert unix timestamp to date in a database query dplyr in R

Tags: r, database, tidyverse, lubridate, dbplyr

Good day, all:

I have a problem involving the use of lubridate (or base R) within a dplyr command to write a database query turning a Unix timestamp (stored as an integer) into a date and then extracting the day from that date variable. The reason I want to do this is that having a date from which I can easily extract time units (Y, Q, M, D, etc.) would allow for some grouping and summary that will reduce the time it takes to query the data using collect().

Within a local session, I can get date and time from a unix timestamp this easily enough

```
df$timestamp <- as_datetime(df$timestamp)
df$Day <- format(as.Date(df$timestamp, format="%Y/%m/%d"),"%d")
```

What I am trying to do is to include this sort of thing directly into a Rpostgres database query using dplyr syntax.

After the usual (and working database connection stuff), I try:

```
%>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::as_datetime(timestamp, origin='1970-01-01', tz = "GMT"))%>%
  select(date)
```

From this I get the error, "Error in as_datetime(timestamp, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT") :
unused arguments (origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")"

However, when I try this:

```
%>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::as_datetime(timestamp))%>%
  select(date)
```

I get this Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to timestamp without time zone LINE 1: SELECT CAST("timestamp" AS TIMESTAMP) AS "date"

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Could you make minimal, reproducible, examples that show the issue, including example data? Preferrably without any Rpostgres. Eg: `lubridate::as_datetime(1656892684, origin='1970-01-01', tz = "GMT")`, `lubridate::as_datetime(1656892684)`

Comment: Caspar, I will see if I can set up a working generic example with a DB stored in memory and then share it. Inspired by your comment, I tried a couple of things, though. First, I just tried to cut and paste the code you sent. It effectively converted the unix timestamp to a date/time so the problem is not related to lubridate being loaded. I also tried within my DB query to just mutate in a new column = 1 and select for that column. That worked too, so the issue is not dplyr per se. It is a combo of lubridate within a dplyr DB query.